# How to run custom rule in Android.mk before compilation?

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile

In Android NDK, I build JNI files generated automatically by SWIG. **callmanager_wrap.cpp** is part of a shared library:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += callmanager_wrap.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But I would like to append/edit `callmanager_wrap.cpp` before compiling. To be more explicit:

```
cat jnistuff.txt >> callmanager_wrap.cpp
```

**Content I need to add is known in advance but callmanager_wrap.cpp is not**. It is generated by SWIG. Ultimately, my custom rule will have to run following command to generate callmanager_wrap.cpp:

```
swig -c++ -java -package com.package.my -o callmanager_wrap.cpp callmanager.i
```

According to [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/hrjsW1jNIAs), it is not possible to add custom rules to `Android.mk`. But in Android sources, I believe there are some `Android.mk` handling steps after BUILT or INSTALLED. I tried the following:

```
MY_JNI_WRAP=callmanager_wrap.cpp

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += callmanager_wrap.cpp

LOCAL_INTERMEDIATE_TARGETS += myjni
myjni:
    echo "in myjni target"
    swig -c++ -java -package com.package.my -o $(MY_JNI_WRAP) callmanager.i
    cat jnistuff.txt >> $(MY_JNI_WRAP)

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But `myjni` target is never called.

1. What is LOCAL_INTERMEDIATE_TARGETS used for?
2. Can I possibly achieve what I want to do here without writing an external script or makefile?

Comment: can you clarify this sentence "I would like to append callmanager_wrap.cpp before compiling"? I can help you if you clear that up a bit.

Comment: Do you really need to run swig on every single build?

Comment: On one hand, it is cleaner and prevent from versioning generated files.
On the other hand, not versioning these files can break the build if developer does not `make clean` after a `git rebase`. But that's a developer's problem. Isn't it possible to custom android makefiles to that extent? I won't hide that I am considering writing a top-script to do just that but I remain curious about this android limitation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += callmanager_wrap.cpp
MY_JNI_WRAP := $(LOCAL_PATH)/callmanager_wrap.cpp

$(MY_JNI_WRAP):
    echo "in myjni target"
    swig -c++ -java -package com.package.my -o $(MY_JNI_WRAP) callmanager.i
    cat jnistuff.txt >> $(MY_JNI_WRAP)
.PHONY: $(MY_JNI_WRAP)

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

That's it.

I probably owe you some explanations. So here we go:

1. `$(LOCAL_SRC_FILES)` is a list of file names relative to `$(LOCAL_PATH)`, so to address a file from outside the standard NDK actions, you need the full path for your file, which is `$(LOCAL_PATH)/callmanager_wrap.cpp`.
2. We specify the file as `.PHONY` to guarantee that the custom action is executed every time you run **ndk-build**. But if you know which are actual dependencies of `callmanager_wrap.cpp`, you can specify them instead, like

   `$(MY_JNI_WRAP): callmanager.i jnistuff.txt $(LOCAL_PATH)/../src/com/package/my/Something.java`

   In this case, you will not need the `.PHONY` line.
3. If you want your source directory to remain clean, you can declare the wrapper file as `.INTERMEDIATE` like this:

   `.INTERMEDIATE: $(MY_JNI_WRAP)`

Now **make** will delete the wrapper file after build, if it did not exist before the build.

Comment: I've tried your proposal with something like: 
`MY_JNI_WRAP:=bus/callmanager_wrap.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(MY_JNI_WRAP)
$(MY_JNI_WRAP):
 echo "in myjni target"
 touch mememe
.PHONY: $(MY_JNI_WRAP)`
But after I ran `rm -rf obj/local/ libs/armeabi && ndk-build -j5`,  `find -name mememe` never returns something. Are you sure .PHONY is recognized by **ndk-build**?

Comment: In my example above, the phony target was not the same string as what I added to LOCAL_SRC_FILES. The trick is that LOCAL_SRC_FILES is relative tothe Android.mk but the make itself and its targets are relative to the current dir. **tl;nr** use $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(MY_JNI_WRAP) everywhere except the LOCAL_SRC_FILES line.

Comment: Wow, you made my day Alex! Thanks heaps

Comment: Using `all: $(MY_JNI_WRAP)` instead of `.PHONY: $(MY_JNI_WRAP)` worked for me.

Comment: Yes, for some reason it didn't. And the rules actually run after compilation, which is fine for me, but not OP.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it this way:
let's say I need to create .s file from .ll file

```
# custom build
source_ll_files := $(wildcard *.ll)
%.s:
    llc -o $@ $(patsubst %.s,%.ll,$@)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(patsubst %.ll,%.s,$(source_ll_files))
# end
```